# Minimum number of PHP modules needed to run Magento

Tags: php-5.4, server-setup

We have the following Modules installed at Rackspace for the old Magento server. They have a new server I am hoping to pair this down. What are the minimum required?

```
php54-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-mysql-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-mbstring-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-ioncube-loader-4.7.4-2.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-cli-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-mcrypt-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-pecl-apc-3.1.13-2.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-xml-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-soap-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-gd-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-pear-1.9.5-2.ius.centos6.noarch
php54-pecl-lzf-1.6.2-8.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-pecl-redis-2.2.5-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-imap-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-process-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-bcmath-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-pdo-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-intl-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-odbc-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
php54-pspell-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
```

Comment: What about Ubuntu 16.04, which package do I need?, I'm trying:
php-curl
php7.0-curl
php-gd
php7.0-gd
php-mcrypt
php7.0-mcrypt
php7.0-mysql
php-xmlrpc
php7.0-xml
php7.0-xmlrpc But I didn't find anything about dom, hash, iconv, pcre, pdo and don't know if those package are find for pdo_mysql or simplexml. :s

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Magento requirements check](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento) is a decent script to run to confirm your server meets the requirements (you need to change the opening PHP tag to `<?php` if your server doesn't support short open tags), and if you open it is has a list of PHP extensions needed, which it lists as:

- `curl`
- `dom`
- `gd`
- `hash`
- `iconv`
- `mcrypt`
- `pcre`
- `pdo`
- `pdo_mysql`
- `simplexml`

**So I'd say you definitely need:**

- `php54-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-mysql-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-mcrypt-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-xml-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-gd-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-pdo-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-intl-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64` (not in requirements checker, pretty sure you need though)
- `php54-soap-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64` (same)

**I'd advise keeping the following:**

- `php54-cli-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64` (useful for shell scripts)
- `php54-pear-1.9.5-2.ius.centos6.noarch` (needed for Megento connect, if used)

**Might be needed depending on modules used / configuration:**

- `php54-mbstring-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64` (needed by some modules, I beleive SagePaySuite needs it)
- `php54-ioncube-loader-4.7.4-2.ius.centos6.x86_64` (only needed if you have ioncube encrypted extensions)
- `php54-pecl-apc-3.1.13-2.ius.centos6.x86_64` (APC cache, check your local.xml)
- `php54-pecl-redis-2.2.5-1.ius.centos6.x86_64` (Redis cache, check your local.xml)

**Not needed:**

- `php54-pecl-lzf-1.6.2-8.ius.centos6.x86_64` (LZF compression)
- `php54-imap-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64` (IMAP mail, very much doubt you need)
- `php54-process-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-bcmath-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-odbc-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`
- `php54-pspell-5.4.38-1.ius.centos6.x86_64`

Oh yeh, also [n98 MageRun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) has a command you can run which is great - `n98-magerun sys:check`, you could set up a temporary server and just install modules until the check comes back clean, or go the opposite was roudn and strip back what you don't feel you need and run the command each time, the output for shows pretty much what the Magento one checks for though:

```
✔ Required PHP Module simplexml found.
✔ Required PHP Module mcrypt found.
✔ Required PHP Module hash found.
✔ Required PHP Module gd found.
✔ Required PHP Module dom found.
✔ Required PHP Module iconv found.
✔ Required PHP Module curl found.
✔ Required PHP Module soap found.
✔ Required PHP Module pdo found.
✔ Required PHP Module pdo_mysql found.
```

Comment: You're fast! `php-soap` and `php-mysql` are required as well. `APC`, `Redis` and/or `Memcached` are optional for caching

Comment: APC opcode cache is really not maintained any more and is not stable (has caused segfaults in production for me too many times). Replace it with "opcache" which is the standard in 5.5+ and install "apcu" if you want to use an APC-compatible user cache. Not sure if CentOS has an opcache package, but if not you can "pecl install zendopcache".

Comment: yum install php54-php-pecl-zendopcache for CentOS

Also it would seem like mb_string should be installed too.  There are a few sporadic references to it in core and EE code.