# autoload error in magento2 on local host

Tags: magento2, localhost, php-5.6, autoloader

I am getting following error during install magento2 on local server.
using php v 5.6

[image: autoload error]

Comment: Was your Magento installation successful ? During installation , were you able to view the magento-2 system requirement info screen ?  At what scenario you got this error ?

Comment: @MGento, I m using php 5.6 v which are compatible for magento 2 requirment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error, your server does not support PHP

make sure your apache server running and your URL like 127.0.0.1/foldername.

Comment: Sir. I already configure 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.Let u know.thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems PHP is not configured well on your server. Check by creating a file in the root directory where you install PHP and.

create `phpinfo.php` and run this file by `localhost/phpinfo.php`

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If this is working fine then you need to install all PHP modules which is required for Magento2.

Check Magento Docs link:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: what type of modules install on this.i checked already using info file .it is supportable version 5.6 .how can resolve this??

Comment: Check link:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/61380

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall PHP and its lib using the command below. I've experienced this same issue when I switched from NGINX to Apache.

```
sudo apt install php-pear php-fpm php-dev php-zip php-curl php-xmlrpc php-gd php-mysql php-mbstring php-xml libapache2-mod-php
```